# Unable to find any video player for Apple TV tvOS with VAST template support

Tags: xcode, tvos, apple-tv

With the new release 4th generation Apple TV, I have been looking at video players that support VAST 2.0 or 3.0 template for a tvOS app.

Due to the lack of HTML 5 support most of the players do not directly support VAST template with tvOS and unable to find any.

Would be great if anyone can point me to a supported player or a workaround.
Thanks

Comment: Have you talked to the providers of native iOS video players (such a JWPlayer, Brightcove, Veeplay)? A port to tvOS shouldn't be too difficult and might already be under development.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. JW Player doesn't support VAST on tvOS. https://github.com/jwplayer/jw-showcase-appletv. Just had a look at the other two you suggested. Cant find any documentation that says Brightcove and Veeplay support VAST.

Comment: Brightcove has a tvOS SDK and Brightcove supports VAST on iOS. So it's probably worth contacting them directly and as for VAST on tvOS. The web site is certainly incomplete regarding tvOS.

Answer (score 0):

I found this one https://atvplayer.zensis.com/features.html
but it is not open source and pricing is unknown. But with watermark works well.